# AutoHotKey get closed/hidden menu item's state (checked/unchecked)

Tags: autohotkey

1. Run this script & Open Notepad
2. Go to the View menu, and toggle the Status Bar
   If the status bar is on, a checkmark will appear next to the menu item, this script tries to detect whether the status bar menu item is checked 
   **The problem is it can only determine checked/nonchecked status after the menu is open, how can I alter the code to detect the checked status while the menu is closed/hidden?**

   Please don't assume that just because I'm using the notepad status bar example, that all I'm trying to do is determine if the notepad status bar is on/off, I'm not. I'm trying to detect if menu items are checked/unchecked.

   ```
   #persistent
   settitlematchmode, 2
   Loop, 
   {
   WinGet, hWnd, ID, Notepad
   hMenu := DllCall("GetMenu", "UPtr", hWnd)
   MenuAndIndex := GetMenuAndIndex(hMenu, "View", "Status Bar")
   State := GetMenuState(MenuAndIndex*)
   if (State.Checked)
       {
       tooltip, View -> Status Bar is checked
       }
   else
   tooltip, View -> Status Bar is unchecked
   }

   ; ------------------FUNCTIONS BELOW -----------------

   GetMenuState(hMenu, Index)
   {
       State := DllCall("GetMenuState", "UPtr", hMenu, "UInt", Index, "UInt", 0x400)
       if (State == -1)
           return False
       return {"CHECKED": State&0x8, "DISABLED": State&0x2, "GRAYED": State&0x2
       , "HILITE": State&0x80, "MENUBARBREAK": State&0x20, "MENUBREAK": State&0x40
       , "OWNERDAW": State&0x100, "POPUP": State&0x10, "SEPARATOR": State&0x800}
   }

   GetMenuAndIndex(hMenu, p*)
   {
       CurrentMenu := hMenu
       For each, MenuName in p
       {
           if SubMenu
               CurrentMenu := SubMenu
           Count := DllCall("GetMenuItemCount", "UPtr", CurrentMenu)
           Loop, % Count
           {
               Index := A_Index - 1
               Name := GetMenuString(CurrentMenu, Index)
               if (RegExReplace(Name, "&|\t.*") = MenuName)
               {
                   SubMenu := DllCall("GetSubMenu", "UPtr", CurrentMenu, "UInt", Index)
                   if SubMenu
                       Continue, 2
                   else
                       return [CurrentMenu, Index]
               }
           }
           return "Item not found"
       }
       return [CurrentMenu, Index]
   }

   GetMenuString(hMenu, Index)
   {
           VarSetCapacity(Name, 256, 0)
           DllCall("GetMenuString", "UPtr", hMenu, "UInt", Index
           , "Str", Name, "Int", 128, "UInt", 0x400)
           return Name
   }
   ```

Comment: Try out [`CheckMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647619(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`GetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980(v=vs.85).aspx) . If `CheckMenuItem` returns `-1`, the menu doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is direct solution for checking if menu items are checked/unchecked without actually opening that menu. So you need indirect ways to do that.

You can check registry keys that menus are changing. For example, from [here](http://lifehacker.com/5602490/enable-the-status-bar-in-notepad-with-a-registry-hack): Notepad in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad` should have registry key for Status Bar. I think many other software is changing registry according to changes from menu. You can use [RegRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/RegRead.htm) command for reading current value of registry key.

Also some software can change `.ini` file according the changes done from menus. You can use [IniRead](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IniRead.htm) command for reading values in `.ini` files.

Use [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) command to search for images on the screen that can be changed by menus. For example, you can search the unique part of Status Bar of Notepad by [ImageSearch](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) command. For example this part:
[image]

There are many other ways to check the for changes done by menus (opens new window, creates file, etc). Focus on what menu changes can change in system and check for these changes.

*Also, always use AutoHotkey and its documenatation from http://ahkscript.org/ (current uptodate version, new official website)! AutoHotkey and its documentation from autohotkey.com is outdated and you may have some problems using them!*